# Payflow Link hosted pages issue with mobile browsers

Tags: paypal, payflowlink

I'm having an issue with forms posting out to https:payflowlink.paypal.com from mobile devices. Instead of returning the hosted checkout page, only a blank page is being served up.

Posting from the same exact form on desktops and tablets brings up the hosted checkout page.

I'm not getting any sort of error message when debugging from mobile safari, just a blank white page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using SECURETOKEN? If so make sure you pass TEMPLATE=MOBILE in the API call to payflowpro.paypal.com or pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com(test). Once you get a result code of "0" you'll redirect to payflowlink.paypal.com and append the URL with your SECURETOKEN and SECURETOKENID and MODE for example:

https://payflowlink.paypal.com?SECURETOKEN=value_from_API_call&SECURETOKENID=Your_made_up_value&MODE=Test (or Live)

Comment: We aren't using SECURETOKEN, do you think that could be the reason that we're getting the blank screen on mobile devices?

Comment: Also, I set up a test post field utilizing the most basic implementation that PayPal recommends and it works desktop but not on mobile. If you want to take a look, it is located here: http://dev.mosaicproductions.org/payflowtest.php

Comment: I would highly recommend using SECURETOKEN. It is not required, but it is most secure. Give it a try and you'll see it work.